# Look for string in posts and postmeta

Tags: wp-query, post-meta

I have a query that finds the usage of an attachment in any post.

```
$used_in_content = array();

foreach ( $attachment_urls as $attachment_url ) {
    $content_query = new WP_Query( array(
        's'              => $attachment_url,
        'post_type'      => 'any',  
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'no_found_rows'  => true,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ) );

    $used_in_content = array_merge( $used_in_content, $content_query->posts );
}
```

However, the string can also be in the posts meta values. How can I change this query, so that it also looks in the post meta values? I tried out different things, but they didn't work. I'm really in the dark here, as I am not really familiar with how these queries work.

Edit: The string can only be found in one additional meta key.

Comment: It's not going to be possible with `WP_Query` without adding every possible meta key to a meta query. You'll probably need to use SQL. (I know this isn't an answer to the question, which is why I didn't post it as one).

Comment: Ok, what if there is only one additional meta key that the string could be in?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: Simply, you cannot combine the search query with meta query. That's how `WP_Query` class is written.